# Setting environment variable when running Python unit tests inside VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, python-unittest

I'd like to execute code inside my unit tests conditioned on whether they're running from within VSCode or the command line.  Is there a way to do so?

The reasoning is to add additional visual feedback through `cv2.imwrite` statements, but to omit these when running a full regression from the command line or when running my CI.

I known that I can set a debugging profile inside `launch.json` and define environment variables there, but this applies only when debugging a unit test:

```
       {
            "name": "Debug Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "test",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "python": "${command:python.interpreterPath}",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "env": {
                "MY_ENVIRONMENT_SWITCH_FOR_WRITING_JPEGS": "1"
            }
        },
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar when not running through the debugger?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT - feature request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try defining environment variables by using `.env` files

[image]

**.env**:

```
MY_ENVIRONMENT_SWITCH_FOR_WRITING_JPEGS = 1
```

**test1.py**:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv

env_path = Path(".") / ".env"
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path, verbose=True)
print(os.getenv("MY_ENVIRONMENT_SWITCH_FOR_WRITING_JPEGS"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your launch.json settings:

```
"purpose": [
    "debug-test"
 ]
```

The rest can remain the same, here is the full snippet:

```
       {
        "name": "Debug Tests",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "test",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "python": "${command:python.interpreterPath}",
        "justMyCode": false,
        "purpose": [
            "debug-test"
        ],
        "env": {
            "MY_ENVIRONMENT_SWITCH_FOR_WRITING_JPEGS": "1"
        }
    },
```

Comment: this worked for me thanks but i had to add {..... "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "test"
            ]